# Can I configure specified PEAP in network-manager

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

Here's the wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
ap_scan=1
network={
    ssid="<SSID Name>"
    proto=WPA2
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
    eap=PEAP
    phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=GTC"
    identity="<User name>"
    password="<Password>"
}
```

I can use wpa_supplicant to connect the wireless, but unfortunately, when I configured these settings in Network Manager, it failed to connect to the network. I wonder what's wrong with that.

Comment: Try running command `wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicat.conf -d`  Replace the terms as in your case. It will give you some output for troubleshooting